# How to Create a matrix of N*N with sum of every ith row and every ith column combined equals to a specific sum?

Tags: matrices

This problem was asked to me in an interview round and was told to just tell the logic!
all the elements in row and column combined should be distinct
For Eg: There is an N=2 and Sum=6
A matrix [3,1]
         [2,3]
satisfies the given condition where 1st Row and 1st column add upto 3+1+2=6 same happens for the second row.

Comment: That's called a [magic square](https://scipython.com/book/chapter-6-numpy/examples/creating-a-magic-square/), minus the requirement of the main diagonal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left[\begin{matrix}0&1&2&\ldots&n-1\\-1&0&1&\cdots&n-2\\-2&-1&0&\cdots&n-3\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\-(n-1)&-(n-2)&-(n-3)&\cdots&0\end{matrix}\right]$$

This matrix has the desired property and all the sums are $0$. If you want all sums to be $N$, simply add $\frac{N}{2n-1}$ to all elements of the matrix.

Comment: but Sir in the second row and second column both have -1 I want all distinct elements to be present in every ith row and ith column . these elements may repeat for any other row and column pair but combined they should be distinct

Comment: I agree, sorry ... Can you please unaccept my answer so that I can delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Pick suitable $b_i$ and $c_j$, and set $a_{i,j}=b_i+c_j$ whenever $i\ne j$. Then adjust $a_{i,i}$ to match the desired sum $S$.

For a concrete example, start with 
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&2&\cdots &n-1\\n&n+1&n+2&\cdots&2n-1\\2n&2n+1&2n+2&\cdots&3n-1\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\n^2-n&n^2-n+1&n^2-n+2&\cdots& n^2-1\end{pmatrix}, $$
which *almost* solves the problem: All entries in row $i$ and column $i$ together are distinct (in fact, all entries of the matrix are distinct).
However, the sum of elements in row $i$ (starting indexing from $0$) is 
$$in+(in+1)+(in+2)+\cdots+(in+n-1)=in^2+\frac{n(n-1)}2,$$
the sum of the elements in column $i$ is
$$i +(n+i)+(2n+i)+\cdots+((n-1)n+i)=\frac{n^2(n-1)}2+ni,$$
so that the sum over row and column is
$$ (n^2+n)i+\frac{(n^2+n)(n-1)}2-(n+1)i=\frac{n^3-n}2+(n^2-1)i.$$
If we replace diagonal elements with other numbers $a_{i,i}$, this becomes
$$ \frac{n^3-n}2+(n^2-n-2)i+a_{i,i}.$$
Hence our goal is to make $$a_{i,i}=S-(n^2-n-2)i.$$
Depending on $S$, some $a_{i,i}$ may become equal to some $a_{i,j}$ or $a_{j,i}$, but in total this forbids at most $n\cdot 2(n-1)$ values of $S$.